# Change hover background of round image css with text in it

Tags: css

Cant do it right way.
Editing html is not allowed

```
<div class="photo_box ">
<h4>LEARN MORE</h4>
<div class="image_frame">
    <div class="image_wrapper"><a href="/lipoparticles-product"><img class="scale-with-grid" src="#" alt="" width="" height=""></a></div>
</div>
<div class="desc">
    <h4>Lipoparticles</h4>
    Lipoparticles are virus-like particles that concentrate membrane proteins in their
    native-conformation. </div>
```

[image]

should be like this :

[image]

[image]

Comment: add your `css` here

Comment: `border-radius`?

Comment: border-radius doesn't help

and css is edited wp-child theme on scss
so it wouldn't help

Comment: do you have image and want to crop that circle from it?

Comment: no, I got this image on page, and I need to add :hover color highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you.

```css
#image{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: red;
  position:relative;
}

#image>span{
  position: absolute;
  color:yellow;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#image:hover{
  /*image will be selected when hover*/

  /*apply changes you want*/
  filter:grayscale(40%);
}
#image:hover>span{
  /*span will be selected when image is hover*/
  color: blue;
}

/*For advance use: pseudo element*/
/*#image:hover::after{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,20%);
}*/
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <span>Text</span>  
</div>
```

Learn about [Beginner Concepts:Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/) and  [different selectors](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/)